# Why the SVG image does not display correctly in the program？

Tags: wpf

I wanna to display SVG file in WPF and I have found that many people recommend by using the `sharpvectors`.

I used it with the XAML as below:

```
<Window x:Class="KongGamLung.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:KongGamLung"        
        xmlns:SVG="http://sharpvectors.codeplex.com/svgc/"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <SVG:SvgViewbox Source="Create.svg" AutoSize="True" OptimizePath="False" TextAsGeometry="True"></SVG:SvgViewbox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Well, the SVG displayed in the editor correctly:
[image]

However, after I ran the program, the SVG has gone.
[image]

Why it turns out to be this? What's more, I have tried several SVG packages in NUGET. But they are worse than this that cannot display even in the editor.

How can I solve this? And if there is a better SVG package than this, please recommend it to me. Thank you.

---

[image]

Comment: Where do you have Create.svg file in your machine? Did you include the file as as a resource in the project?

Comment: I edited the topic yet. I create it by adobe illustrator and have included as a resource in the project.@MathivananKP

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have 2 options.

1. If you set the svg file's Build Action to "Content", then you should set Copy to Output Directory to "Copy Always" or "Copy if newer".
2. If you set the svg file's Build Action to "Resource", it goes as assembly resource that can be accessed by a [Resource File Pack URI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf).

Then you can use it in XAML like below and you can set Copy to Output Directory to "Do not Copy".

```
<SVG:SvgViewbox Source="Create.svg"
                AutoSize="True" OptimizePath="False" TextAsGeometry="True"/>
```

Comment: I did as option 2 and it works. I wonder if it is visual studio cause this or the sharpvectors? I am scared of these things for it does not report any error.

Comment: I'm wondering why the Pack URI prefix is necessary here. If you set the Source property of an Image element to an assembly resource path, you can omit it in XAML, because the XAML parser adds it automatically. Does `Source="/Create.svg"` perhaps work?